# creating image host service using $php

Tags: php, html, css

*fix my code please iam getting error : C:\xampp\tmp\php7A7B.tmp*
i get this error while uploading image , can you fix it pls

**otherwise**: i want everyimage uploaded on this service add on my uploads folder

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>imgfox upload images</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   image:
   <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>

<?php 
// connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("meinimages") or die(mysql_error());

// file properties
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
}
if (!isset($file))
    echo "please choose a image.";
else
{
 $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));  
 $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
 $image_size = getimagesize($image);

 if ($image_size==FALSE)
     echo "you try upload no/..image.";
else
 {
    if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')"))
      echo "problem while upload $image.";
    else
    {
      $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
      echo "image is uploaded.<p />your image:<p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
    }



 }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error? Specifically what line the error is occurring on.

Comment: its not give me a linecode al the info about error is on the question

Comment: That error is coming from:
    echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

Comment: CAN YOU GIVE ME THE CORRECT ONE?

Comment: There's not enough information here to tell, are you getting any more output?

Comment: no just this error

Comment: any help ? i should finish it before 7 jun i just got that error could someone else send me the true code ?

Comment: You seem to refer to $file before it every get set. Perhaps remove the if condition.

Comment: ok , can you tell me the code that make everyimage get uploaded in this service stored in a folder ? @linead